# Validating a JAX-RS response produced asynchronously

Tags: java, validation, asynchronous, jax-rs

According to the JAX-RS 2.0 spec, in order to validate a synchronous response produced by a resource method, one would need to annotate this method with the `@Valid` annotation. However, the spec does not mention anything related to validating asynchronous responses.

Any ideas on how to go about this please?

Thank you.